# Help me optimize this query. Please

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

```
$query_index_neighborhood1 = 
"SELECT areas_db.areas_name, areas_db.areas_id, neighborhoods_db.neighborhoods_id,
neighborhoods_db.neighborhoods_name, neighborhoods_db.neighborhoods_area_id, 
areas_db.areas_state_id 
FROM (
       (
         (
            restaurants_db 
            INNER JOIN neighborhoods_db ON neighborhoods_db.neighborhoods_id=restaurants_db.restaurants_neighborhood
         ) 
         INNER JOIN areas_db ON areas_db.areas_id=neighborhoods_db.neighborhoods_area_id
       )
       INNER JOIN areas_db AS areas_db1 on areas_db1.areas_id=restaurants_db.restaurants_area
    )
WHERE areas_db.areas_state_id=$mxstateid
GROUP BY neighborhoods_db.neighborhoods_id
ORDER BY areas_db.areas_id, neighborhoods_db.neighborhoods_name ASC";
```

Comment: might want to paste your 'create table' statements for that so people can see what you have already got as your indexes, and maybe a describe on the query. no body can help you much with out all the info

Comment: What indexes do you have on your tables?

Comment: What's with all the parantheses?

Comment: Run that query and type the word Explain in front of it, so you will do Explain Select areas.... and MySQL will give you a good look into exactly what is going on with your query

Comment: You don't need all those brackets in the join clauses. That kind of hideous crud is something Microsoft Access tries to impose on the world.

Answer (score 0):

As an interesting thought exercise, I came up with the following:

```
SELECT a.areas_name,
    a.areas_id,
    n.neighborhoods_id,
    n.neighborhoods_name,
    n.neighborhoods_area_id, 
    a.areas_state_id 
FROM neighborhoods_db AS n
INNER JOIN areas_db AS a ON a.areas_id = n.neighborhoods_area_id
WHERE a.areas_state_id = $mxstateid
    AND n.neighborhoods_id in (SELECT restaurants_neighborhood FROM restaurants_db)
ORDER BY a.areas_id, n.neighborhoods_name ASC
```

Also, table aliases are your friend.